# PySpark pivot UnsafeArrayData cannot be cast to InternalRow

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm managing highly nested data and I've stumbled upon a very strange behavior. Consider the following code:

```py
t = base.select("id", sqlFunctions.explode("options.AttributeChoice").alias("attribute_data")) \
  .select(["id", "attribute_data.attributeName", sqlFunctions.explode("attribute_data.allowedValues.value")]) \
  .withColumnRenamed("attributeName", "attribute_name") \
  .withColumnRenamed("col", "attribute_value") \
  .groupBy(["id", "attribute_name"]).agg(sqlFunctions.count("attribute_value").alias("attribute_value"))

t \
  .groupBy(["id"]).pivot("attribute_name").agg(sqlFunctions.first(sqlFunctions.col("attribute_value"))) \
  .limit(4).toPandas()
```

Works just fine, in fact, it outputs:

```
+-----+-----+----+
|   id|color|size|
+-----+-----+----+
|01.  |    2|   2|
|02.  |    2|   2|
|03.  |    2|   2|
|04.  |    2|   2|
+-----+-----+----+
```

However, if we change the last instruction from `limit(4).toPandas()` to `.count()` we get an error:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 918.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.3 in stage 918.0 (TID 855) (10.139.64.28 executor 0): java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnsafeArrayData cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.InternalRow

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-918281217424574> in <module>
      9   .fillna(0)
     10 
---> 11 t \
     12   .groupBy(["id"]).pivot("attribute_name").max("attribute_value").fillna(0, subset=["size", "color"]) \
     13   .count()

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in count(self)
    686         2
    687         """
--> 688         return int(self._jdf.count())
    689 
    690     def collect(self):

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1302 
   1303         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1304         return_value = get_return_value(
   1305             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1306 

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
    115     def deco(*a, **kw):
    116         try:
--> 117             return f(*a, **kw)
    118         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
    119             converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324             value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325             if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o9687.count.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 918.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.3 in stage 918.0 (TID 855) (10.139.64.28 executor 0): java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnsafeArrayData cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.InternalRow
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.GenericArrayData.getStruct(GenericArrayData.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificPredicate.subExpr_0$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificPredicate.eval(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FilterExec.$anonfun$doExecute$3(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:271)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FilterExec.$anonfun$doExecute$3$adapted(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:270)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:515)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:491)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$ConcatIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:224)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:513)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:491)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$ConcatIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:224)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.HashAggregateExec.$anonfun$doExecute$2(HashAggregateExec.scala:144)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.HashAggregateExec.$anonfun$doExecute$2$adapted(HashAggregateExec.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndex$2(RDD.scala:920)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndex$2$adapted(RDD.scala:920)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:380)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:344)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:380)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:344)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.$anonfun$runTask$3(ShuffleMapTask.scala:81)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.$anonfun$runTask$1(ShuffleMapTask.scala:81)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:153)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.$anonfun$run$1(Task.scala:122)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$13(Executor.scala:824)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1621)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:827)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:683)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2973)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2920)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2914)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2914)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1334)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1334)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1334)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3182)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3123)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3111)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnsafeArrayData cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.InternalRow
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.GenericArrayData.getStruct(GenericArrayData.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificPredicate.subExpr_0$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificPredicate.eval(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FilterExec.$anonfun$doExecute$3(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:271)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FilterExec.$anonfun$doExecute$3$adapted(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:270)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:515)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:491)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$ConcatIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:224)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:513)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:491)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$ConcatIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:224)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.HashAggregateExec.$anonfun$doExecute$2(HashAggregateExec.scala:144)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.HashAggregateExec.$anonfun$doExecute$2$adapted(HashAggregateExec.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndex$2(RDD.scala:920)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndex$2$adapted(RDD.scala:920)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:380)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:344)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:380)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:344)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.$anonfun$runTask$3(ShuffleMapTask.scala:81)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.$anonfun$runTask$1(ShuffleMapTask.scala:81)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:153)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.$anonfun$run$1(Task.scala:122)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$13(Executor.scala:824)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1621)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:827)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:683)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Update (add the schema):

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- color: long (nullable = true)
 |-- size: long (nullable = true)
```

The problem is definitely caused by the pivoting expression, as removing that section - the whole `groupBy(...).pivot(...).agg(...)` works just fine.

I tried replacing `agg(sqlFunctions.first(sqlFunctions.col("attribute_value")))` with a `.max("attribute_value")` to ascertain if the problem was caused by non-DataFrame operations but the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

it's hard to give a correct solution, why don't take a try to check data types and update the question post with printSchema() results , Then someone can help you better.

```
  temp_df = t.groupBy(["id"])\
.pivot("attribute_name")
.agg(sqlFunctions.first(sqlFunctions.col("attribute_value")))

temp_df.printSchema()
```

Comment: You are absolutely right, my bad. I added the schema!